# cut the string and take its part for the function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace, split

```
function replace_tags(input, email) {
    return input
    .replace("{randomip}", random.ip)
    .replace("{email}", email)
    .replace("{date}", random.date)
    .replace("{random_number_4}", random.number(4))
}
```

I have the above function to change a string that is inputted by the user into a return value of a function or variable

well here i am `{random_number_4}`
I want to break the string and take the number 4 to be used as a parameter in the function `random.number(4)`

I want if the user enters the {random_number_x} string it will get `random.number(x)`

What method do I most likely do to break and replace the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `replace` callback function:

```
function replace_tags(input, email) {
    return input
    .replace("{randomip}", random.ip)
    .replace("{email}", email)
    .replace("{date}", random.date)
    .replace(/\{random_number_(\d+)\}/g, (_, n) => random.number(n))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex with a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```js
var random = {
  number: (x) => Math.floor(Math.random() * x)
};

function replace_tags(input, email) {
    return input
      .replace("{randomip}", random.ip)
      .replace("{email}", email)
      .replace("{date}", random.date)
      .replace(/{random_number_(\d+)}/g, (_, number) => random.number(number))
}

console.log(replace_tags('test {email} {random_number_4} {random_number_8}', 'test@example.com'));
```